# MultiColumn Spring Roo scaffold with Spring MVC

Tags: java, css, spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo

Maybe I'm asking something lame or maybe I’m too lazy, but still. Here it goes:

Has anybody found an easy way to obtain two columns in the scaffolded views generated by Spring Roo?

I'm very new to Spring Roo. Well in fact very new to Spring Framework, Apache tiles, jspx and tagx, for that matter.

I'm looking for a way to modify the way Spring Roo generates the view (if there’s any), so it would be much easier for us to drastically do a makeover in the future.

I know the list of shown fields comes from the Spring Roo generated file: view/*SOMEPATH*/xxx.jspx, where "xxx.jspx" could be create.jspx, for instance.

If I don’t want to touch the generated jspx file, with a list of "id's" I could manually modify the presentation doing something like this in css:

```
#c_xxxx_yyy1, 
#c_xxxx_yyy2, 
#c_xxxx_yyy3, 
#c_xxxx_yyy4, 
#c_xxxx_yyy5 {
    stuff;
}
```

It's a lot of work if you have many entities with many fields in them. Maybe it’s easier to modify every view. (As always)

You could also do something like the following (of course with the css should be in a resource file):

```
    --- create.jspx: ---
...
  <style>                          // ADD THIS
    .something                     // ADD THIS
    {                              // ADD THIS
      background-color:#b0c4de;    // ADD THIS
    }                              // ADD THIS
  </style>                         // ADD THIS
<form:create ...
    <field:select ...
    <field:select ...
    <field:select ...
    <div class="something">        // ADD THIS
        <field:input ...
        <field:input ...
        <field:input ...
        <field:input ...
    </div>                         // ADD THIS
...
```

Maybe there is a way to add a custom css class for all the odd fields, and another for all the even fields. Or maybe with a counter.

I know this doesn't sound feasible. I thought it's better to ask.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Forgot to say I'm using Spring and Spring MVC 3.2.3.RELEASE, and Spring Roo 1.2.4.RELEASE [rev 75337cf].

Comment: I treat Spring Roo as a means to generate boiler-plate.  I don't think it's intent is to push a button and have a complete, customized solution.  In fact, in the last 20 projects I did with Roo, I didn't even generate a single scaffold, but chose rather to use plan-vanilla Controllers and make my own JSPs.  Long story short, I think if you want to customize the views Spring Roo generates, you are stuck modifying the JSP file(s).

Comment: @CodeChimp: Yes. That's what I was thinking when I finished writing the post. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: No problem.  If you find a solution I would love to see it.  I have taken to only using Roo to generate my JPA entities, empty services and controllers, and to bootstrap the Spring Security stuff.  Other than that I like to control most of the other code myself.

Comment: I don't think I will be able to spend time in this. At least not now. I'm now doing the `<div class="something">` as I mentioned earlier. Nevertheless I was hoping someone liked the idea or had a solution already. hahaha.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a change to the formatting that affects many entities, you can modify the custom tags generated by spring roo.

Spring roo includes a set of custom tags (tagx) which are used by all the views (jspx) to present the markup.  These tags are only downloaded by spring roo console on the first time you make a scaffolding.  So you are OK to change these without losing changes in the future.

However, for new versions of spring roo, you can ask for these tags to be re-downloaded, which will overwrite any existing ones.

Therefore, I recommend the following approach (assuming you were changing the table layout):

```
copy table.tagx to tableWithTwoColumns.tagx
customize tableWithTwoColumns.tagx as required
modify any views that need to use this new column to use tableCustom
```

The markup generated by spring roo is using tables which is not recommended for modern websites, so I would not recommend doing any more than tweaks to the layouts (unless you can convert the tags to use float div's instead of tables).

Comment: Please excuse me if I'm asking nonesense, but I'm new to tiles and tags. In my project there is a generated create.jspx with a list of fields inside a `<form:create ...`. I couldn't find `table` used anywhere in form/create.jspx or other files used in it (like tags/form/create.tagx, for example).

Comment: _**First**_ Would it be correct if I do the following?: **a)** create my tableWithColumns tagx file with a `rows` and `columns` integer parameters, **b)** add the namespace `xmlns:table="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/form/fields"`, **c)** add a `<table:tableWithColumns rows=5 columns=2 ... >` before the fields in the create.jspx and `</field:tableWithColumns>` afterwards?

Comment: _**Second**_ The current table.tagx uses a parameter to pass the data, not sure how to take it from the lines... maybe with `<jsp:doBody />`, but then how to do a foreach?